# What are the names of these vegetables?

Tags: food-identification

[image: Vegetables marked with circles]

I made some guesses about what the vegetables are, but some I am not sure about. Also, for the first one circled, I searched the image and found parsnips, but parsnips is not on the list. Here's what I came up with so far:

```
Artichoke9 Corn27 Chicory16  Squash2 Tomato4
Leek24 Brussel Sprouts35  Pepper/Capsicum3 Cauliflower30
Brocolli11   Water Cress8  Turnip?5  Green Bean/French Beans17
Lettuce32 Asparagus15  Potato33 Spinach1
Avocado Eggplant/Aubergine20 Kale Radish31
Celery13  Onion  Carrot19  Parsley
Mushroom25 Snow Peas Pumpkin5 Cabbage
Cucumber21 Beetroot ?? Chilli/Hot Pepper Celery12 Beans18 Zuchini/Courgette22
```

Comment: What did a google image search for all the vegetable names yield?

Comment: There are various pictures for those vegetable- they don't match well. E.g.The first one says Parsnip which is not on their list

Comment: Is this an English learning lesson? It's an odd mixture of American English and British English. Americans don't generally use "courgette" but British people use "aubergine" instead of eggplant (which is one word, not two).

Comment: @Catija Agree it's quite an odd mix. Found it online and it appears that it's *supposed* to be for British English. Seems that people develop these worksheets and upload them, so it's quite possible that there are irregularities or mistakes filtering through. To say the least, some of the images would be hard for me to identify.

Comment: Found 1 mistake - parsley is listed twice. (#7 & #29) Most likely one of those should have been parsnips.

Comment: 2nd mistake - avocado is not on the list. There are 36 images, not 35 as per the list!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let me say that this worksheet is not at all well put together. In addition to somewhat poor images, there are a couple of mistakes. As per my comments, parsley is listed twice (one should have been parsnips) and avocado is not on the answer list. The list only has 35 items and there are 36 images.

But because we have a user that wants to learn and needs some help, I am going to answer. For the purpose of the answers we are going to call parsnips #29, and avocado #36.

So here's how the answer should look:

Row 1:

9-artichoke, 27-corn on the cob, 29-parsnips, 2-squash, 4-tomato

Row 2:

24-leek, 35-brussels sprouts, 3-pepper, 30-cauliflower

Row 3:

11-broccoli, 8-watercress, 6-turnip, 17-green/French beans

Row 4:

32-lettuce, 15-asparagus, 33-potatoes, 1-spinach

Row 5:

36-avocado, 20-eggplant, 23-kale, 31-radish

Row 6:

13-celery 2 (celery root), 28-onion, 19-carrots, 7-parsley

Row 7:

25-mushrooms, 34-peas (green peas), 5-pumpkins, 14-cabbage

Row 8:

22-courgettes, 10-beetroot, 16-chicory, 26-red hot pepper, 12-celery 1, 18-beans, 21-cucumbers

Comment: Have you got some links to similar real images- at least the circled vegetables?

Comment: @user2617804 As suggested in the first comment to your question, try google image search. It will work extremely well for basic things like this. For example: [parsnips](https://www.google.com/search?q=parsnips&tbm=isch) and [watercress](https://www.google.com/search?q=watercress&tbm=isch).